# How can we use VS2013's brwoser link feature against IE7 / IE8?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, web-essentials, browserstack, browser-link

With [Web Essentials 2013](https://github.com/madskristensen/webEssentials2013/) in Visual Studio 2013's Browser Link feature, we can hook IDE with developer tools of any browser.

Can we hook it with IE7 and IE8 in the same manner? Perhaps using BrowserStack or those running inside Hyper-V VMs from http://modern.ie/ (using IIS Express or ASP development server)? I couldn't find anything on the internet about old versions.

Answer (score 0):

right now I don't have an older version of that browsers in my computer, so I can't test/confirm, but technically Browser-Link it's built on top of SignalR so it should use the right fallback (long polling, forever-frame and so on).

Finally, it **should** work.